# How to use properly my unique LAMBA formula instead of a copied down formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I try to use a MAKEARRAY/LAMBA so I don't have to use a copied down formula but I struggle.

In the example below I try to retreive an array of country in **H2:H** corresponding to dishes **G2:G**. Good to know : Columns (Countries) **B2:E2** may extend, and rows (dishes) **B3:E** may also extend

[image: Picture of the example here if you want a better view of the problem]

I first tried to build a formula with **BYCOL/LAMBDA** to copy it down from **H2**, and it worked :

```
LET(
Γ;B$2:E;
Δ;G2;
Σ;XMATCH(TRUE;BYCOL(Γ;LAMBDA(col;REGEXMATCH(CONCATENATE(col);Δ))));
IF(LEN(Δ);INDEX(Γ; 1; Σ);)
)
```

And tried in **I2** to build a unique formula with **MAKEARRAY/LAMBDA** (not working):

```
LET(
Γ;B$2:E;
Δ;G2:G;
Σ;XMATCH(TRUE;BYCOL(Γ;LAMBDA(col;REGEXMATCH(CONCATENATE(col);Δ))));
MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(Δ);1;LAMBDA(r;c;IF(LEN(Δ);INDEX(Γ; 1; Σ);)))
)
```

Two questions then :

- How can I make this last formula work?
- Is my way of thinking (BYCOL-> REGEXMATCH -> CONCATENATE) the best (optimal) way to work out my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(G2:G;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;torow(index(if(B3:E=Σ;B2:E2;));1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Really helpfull ! Torow, another keyword to learn. I can see you you've set a **B2:E2** Will this work if I had a column "UK" for example after Column **E** ?

Comment: then the ranges within the formula ought to be `B3:F` & `B2:F2`

Comment: sure. But what I wanted to know is, is there a way to make this more dynamic, something like like a **B2:2**. This way we don't have to edit the formula